# Failed to set httpOnly flag for all gwt response with tomcat 6.0.18

Tags: java, tomcat, http-headers, session-cookies

I'm working with an application written in GWT 2.5.1 with GXT 2.3.1 runing on tomcat 6.0.18
and I am trying to set the httpOnly flag to true in all cookie.
But currently I'm stuck.

I have tried numerous ways to to solve the situation.:

I've tried to set the

```
<Context useHttpOnly="true">
```

in the tomcat's context.xml but it turned out this feature only supported from tomcat v 6.0.19

after that I've tried to setup a webfilter

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>headersFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>headersFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>[filter.class.location].HeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

And in the filter i've implemented the following:

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response,
                                        final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;

        // if errors exist then create a sanitized cookie header and continue
        final SecurityWrapperResponse securityWrapperResponse = new SecurityWrapperResponse(httpResponse, "sanitize");
        final Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                final Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
                if (cookie != null) {
                    if (ESAPI.securityConfiguration().getHttpSessionIdName().equals(cookie.getName())) {
                        securityWrapperResponse.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        httpResponse.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, httpResponse);
    }
```

I've also tried to call the filterChain.doFilter(request, httpResponse); in the begining.
But in as it turned out the first rpc call has no cookie there fore the response does not pass the if (cookies != null)  statement. But right after the the doFilter ended I got a cookie in firebug without httponly flag. :(

Currently I've trying to find out how to set a cookie for the first call.

The posibble soulutions i'm thinking about is to set a

```
   response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid
                + "; Path=" + contextPath + "; HttpOnly" + secure);
```

statement in each and every request but it could be an overkill.

Could somebody help me out with this?

Comment: GWT won't mess with your webapp, it's not the culprit. You can [edit] your question to remove GWT and (hopefully) reach a wider audience (people knowledgeable about Tomcat might skip it because they don't know GWT)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with a lot's of investigation it turned out the problem is that the first RPC sent out from the client has no cookie setted and thats why the filter cannot find it.